# static IP not saving in LAN properties

Tags: networking, ip, tcpip

static ip is not saving int lan tcp/ip properties i.e
once I enter a static address with subnet mask, default gateway Etc.. it accepts the details, but then I close the dialog and when I come back in to make sure all is set OK, all static details have disappeared and I am left with the automatic setting once again in my windows 8 lap.

Comment: Hello, we'll need more information; the basics like: Which OS are you talking about?  Is this you personal computer or a work computer? Is this a real computer or a VM or alike?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 os is windows 8 this is my real personal lap